# How to combine objects from different .obj files?

Tags: graphics, modeling

I got a [screw .obj](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jllgosx9qg0ra3h/screw.obj?dl=0) model with the head diameter of `2cm`, and a [board .obj](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0m4rons7kl804jz/board.obj?dl=0) model of `10cmx10cmx4cm` in dimension. I would like the screw duplicated in 25 copies painted with different color and "screw" on the board in an array of `5x5` with random heights. How can I attain this in Mathematica?

[image]

```
(* assuming the .obj files are located in the c: root *)
scw = Import["c:\\screw.obj"];
brd = Import["c:\\board.obj"];
Show[brd, Graphics3D[{
   Translate[
    Rotate[First[scw], 2 Pi , {0, 0, 1}], {1, 0.8, -1}] ,
   Translate[
    Rotate[First[scw], 2 Pi , {0, 0, 1}], { 3, 1, -1}],
   Translate[
    Rotate[First[scw], 2 Pi , {0, 0, 1}], {5, 1.1, -1}] ,
   Translate[
    Rotate[First[scw], 2 Pi , {0, 0, 1}], {7, 0.7, -1}] ,
   Translate[
    Rotate[First[scw], 2 Pi , {0, 0, 1}], {9, 1.0, -1}] 
    }]
 ]
```

With the code shown above, I got something like this:

[image]

I need a better(faster) way to do this, and need to knew how to "paint" the nails and the board.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you mean by "screw on the board". Do you mean align the screw so the head is flush with a face of the board? Can you show what you have tried so far, or what you are having difficulty with?

Comment: user16069: please consider choosing a more "human" user name.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, from now on I'll call myself "Putterboy".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this:

```
s = Import["screw.obj"];

b = Import["board.obj"];

scr = First[s];
brd = First[b];

screwList = 
  Table[{Hue[(5 i + j)/25], 
    Translate[scr, {2 i - 1, RandomReal[{-.5, 2}], 1 - 2 j}]}, {i, 
    5}, {j, 5}];

Graphics3D[Join[{Brown, brd}, screwList],Lighting->"Neutral"]
```

> [image: screws]

I added the board to the same `Graphics3D` as the screws, instead of using `Show`. Also, I abbreviated the application of `First`, and used colors from `Hue`. The "height" measured from the board is a random number.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and I see that the rotations in my code are completely not necessary.